# Dividir array de acordo com os tipos de pagamento

Tags: php, array, session, post

Código da **index.php**

```
 <form action="add-to-cart2.php" method="post">

   <label for="">Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="nome">
   <br> <br>

   <label for="">Dinheiro</label>
   <input type="text" name="dinheiro">
   <br> <br>

   <label for="">Cheque</label>
   <input type="text" name="cheque">
   <br> <br>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Como podem observar, é um formulário bem simples contendo três campos.

A página **add-to-cart2.php** irá receber o valor dos **input's** e armazenar em um **array**.

Código da página **add-to-cart2.php**:

```
   session_start();

   if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
      $_SESSION['cart'] = [];
   }

   array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_POST);
```

Ao usar o **print_r** irá ficar desta maneira:

```
Array
(
    [nome] => Mathews
    [dinheiro] => 50
    [cheque] => 100
)
```

Entretanto, eu gostaria que o resultado fosse algo parecido com um **fluxo de caixa**, ou seja, desta maneira:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nome] => Mathews
            [dinheiro] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nome] => Mathews
            [cheque] => 100
        )


)
```

Estou fazendo com $_SESSION, pois estou fazendo como um carrinho de compras, ou seja, adicionar / remover / alterar, tudo isto na mesma $_SESSION.

Eu sei que um dos erros que eu esteja cometendo é atribuir o valor direto de **$_POST** para a **$_SESSION**. Já fiz várias alterações mas nenhuma chegou perto do que eu desejo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma é definir manualmente a forma que deseja inserir na sessão. Para adicionar somente os campos nome e dinheiro:

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], ["nome" => $_POST['nome'], "dinheiro" => $_POST['dinheiro']]);
```

Ou para adicionar os campos nome e cheque:

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], ["nome" => $_POST['nome'], "cheque" => $_POST['cheque']]);
```

Utilizando as duas formas no lugar de `array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_POST)` você terá a saída desejada.